# if else statement goes through both if and else when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I am having some trouble with an `if` `else` statement and I can't figure out why it's working the way it is. When I click the button it will run through the `if` statement and straight away run through the `else` statement.

```js
var s,
  PasswordShowHide = {
    settings: {
      passwordInput: $('#password'),
      showHideButton: $('.password-toggle')
    },

    init: function() {
      s = this.settings;
      this.bindUIActions();
    },

    bindUIActions: function() {
      s.showHideButton.on("touchend click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // var inputType = s.passwordInput.attr('type');

        // console.log(inputType);
        if (s.passwordInput.attr('type') === "password") {
          s.passwordInput.attr("type", "text");
          console.log("Changed to text");
          s.showHideButton.html("Hide");
        } else {
          s.passwordInput.attr("type", "password");
          console.log("Changed to password");
          s.showHideButton.html("Show");
        }
      });
    }

  };


(function() {
  PasswordShowHide.init();
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
    Password
    <button type="button" class="password-toggle">Show</button>
    <input id="password" type="password" name="password" autocomplete="off" required>
</label>
```

This is my app.js for the webpack

```
/**
 * First we will load all of this project's JavaScript dependencies which
 * includes Vue and other libraries. It is a great starting point when
 * building robust, powerful web applications using Vue and Laravel.
 */

// Vendor Files
// ------------------------------
// Autocomplete: http://projects.sergiodinislopes.pt/flexdatalist/
require('./vendor/jquery.flexdatalist.min');

// Components
// require('./components/disable');
require('./components/passwordValidator');
require('./components/passwordShowHide');
require('./components/select');
require('./components/showHide');
require('./components/date');
require('./components/menuDropdown');
```

Comment: First of all - that is _impossible_. Likely your function is called more than once - so you are looking at two _independent_ function outputs here.

Comment: Could it be that the whole event handler is run twice? Did you click twice? Or get both a `touchend` and a `click`?

Comment: Changed your code into a snippet, seems to run fine. Your problem must be elsewhere in your code.

Comment: There is no explanation rather then you call the  `PasswordShowHide.init()` twice !

Comment: It's going through the init twice. Since I'm using webpack it combines everything together. Any thoughts on how to stop this? @bRIMOs

Comment: It's running through twice on all my functions. I was going off this: https://css-tricks.com/how-do-you-structure-javascript-the-module-pattern-edition/ for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

Your event handler handles "touchend" and "click". Depending on the device type, it will be called twice; probably what happens here is that on the first call, you set the input's attribute "type" to password in the else clause, and on the second call it goes into the if-part.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your event handler is called more than once. You have attached both touchend and click events to the element. Since all you are doing is toggling the type in the input element, it looks like that both if and else are run. Confirm this by putting a debugger on the event handler. You will know that the handler is called more than once.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Found that this particular collation of views in my Laravel had app.js running twice in the HTML.

Thanks everyone for trying to help.